# Socket bind() failed with Invalid argument error for program running on MacOS

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, bind

I'm trying to run a simple C program which uses the bind() function to bind a IPv4/IPv6 address to a socket.

Below is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socket_fd = -1, addrlen = 0, af;
    struct sockaddr_storage addr = {0};
    unsigned connections = 0;
    pthread_t workers[WORKER_NUM] = { 0 };
    int client_sock_fds[WORKER_NUM] = { 0 };
    char ip_string[64];

    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "inet6") == 0) {
        af = AF_INET6;
        init_sockaddr_inet6((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&addr);
    }
    else {
        af = AF_INET;
        init_sockaddr_inet((struct sockaddr_in *)&addr);
    }

    printf("[Server] Create socket\n");
    socket_fd = socket(af, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_fd < 0) {
        perror("Create socket failed");
        goto fail;
    }

    printf("[Server] Bind socket\n");
    addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, addrlen) < 0) {
        perror("Bind failed");
        goto fail;
    }

    printf("[Server] Listening on socket\n");
    if (listen(socket_fd, 3) < 0) {
        perror("Listen failed");
        goto fail;
    }

    printf("[Server] Wait for clients to connect ..\n");
    while (connections < WORKER_NUM) {
        client_sock_fds[connections] =
            accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t *)&addrlen);
        if (client_sock_fds[connections] < 0) {
            perror("Accept failed");
            break;
        }

        if (sockaddr_to_string((struct sockaddr *)&addr, ip_string,
                               sizeof(ip_string) / sizeof(ip_string[0]))
            != 0) {
            printf("[Server] failed to parse client address\n");
            goto fail;
        }

        printf("[Server] Client connected (%s)\n", ip_string);
        if (pthread_create(&workers[connections], NULL, run,
                           &client_sock_fds[connections])) {
            perror("Create a worker thread failed");
            shutdown(client_sock_fds[connections], SHUT_RDWR);
            break;
        }

        connections++;
    }

    if (connections == WORKER_NUM) {
        printf("[Server] Achieve maximum amount of connections\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < WORKER_NUM; i++) {
        pthread_join(workers[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("[Server] Shuting down ..\n");
    shutdown(socket_fd, SHUT_RDWR);
    sleep(3);
    printf("[Server] BYE \n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

fail:
    printf("[Server] Shuting down ..\n");
    if (socket_fd >= 0)
        close(socket_fd);
    sleep(3);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

```
static void
init_sockaddr_inet(struct sockaddr_in *addr)
{
    /* 0.0.0.0:1234 */
    addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr->sin_port = htons(1234);
    addr->sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
}

static void
init_sockaddr_inet6(struct sockaddr_in6 *addr)
{
    /* [::]:1234 */
    addr->sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    addr->sin6_port = htons(1234);
    addr->sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
}
```

When this program is compiled and run on Linux it works without any errors. But when the same program is compiled and run on MacOS, the bind() function returns an "Invalid Argument" error.

I checked the man page for the bind() function to see what the possible reasons for this error could be. The three possible reasons were:

1. The socket was already bound to another address
2. The `addrlen` value passed to the function is incorrect
3. The `addr` is not a valid address for this socket's domain

I was able to verify that it wasn't due to the first and third reason.

My question would be as to why does the `addrlen` value passed to the bind() function throw an "Incorrect argument" error when ran on a Unix system but works perfectly fine when ran on a Linux system?

Comment: Does it work if you initialize `addrlen` to `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)` or `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)` respectively to address family?

Comment: Yes it does work if I initialise `addrlen` to `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)` or `sizeof(struct sockkaddr_in6)`. But I am trying to figure out why using of the size of the `sockaddr_storage` works on Linux and not on Unix

Comment: The only mention of clear `addrlen` requirement i found [here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc/lr2/lrv2ch18.htm): _addrlen should be greater than or equal to the size of the sockaddr or sockaddr_in structure_. Probably it's implementation defined. Or bug in one of the implementations.

Comment: @dimich that looks like a typo to me. It says `addr` for `AF_INET` (no mention of `AF_INET6`) must point to a `sockaddr` or `sockaddr_in` struct, and `addrlen` must be the byte size of the struct, but then goes on to say `addrlen` can be larger than the struct.

Answer (score 2):

The `addrlen` value you pass to `bind()` must exactly match the address family you specify in `socket()`.  That means `addrlen` must be set to `sizeof(sockaddr_in)` for `AF_INET`, and `sizeof(sockaddr_in6)` for `AF_INET6`.  Using `sizeof(sockaddr_storage)` is the wrong value, as `sockaddr_storage` is designed to be large enough to hold all possible `sockaddr_...` types, so its size may be larger than `sockaddr_in6`.

On the other hand, when calling `accept()`, you need to set `addrlen` to the full size of `addr` beforehand, so it knows how much memory it has to work with when writing the client's address to `addr`.  `addrlen` will be adjusted to the actual size written.  However, you can't simply type-cast an `int*` into a `socklen_t*`, so `addrlen` needs to be an actual `socklen_t` type.  Besides, `bind()` is expecting a `socklen_t` anyway, not an `int`.

Try something more like this instead:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socket_fd = -1, af;
    socklen_t addrlen; // <-- add this!
    struct sockaddr_storage addr = {0};
    unsigned connections = 0;
    pthread_t workers[WORKER_NUM] = { 0 };
    int client_sock_fds[WORKER_NUM] = { 0 };
    char ip_string[64];

    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "inet6") == 0) {
        af = AF_INET6;
        addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6); // <-- add this!
        init_sockaddr_inet6((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&addr);
    }
    else {
        af = AF_INET;
        addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); // <-- add this!
        init_sockaddr_inet((struct sockaddr_in *)&addr);
    }

    printf("[Server] Create socket\n");
    socket_fd = socket(af, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_fd < 0) {
        perror("Create socket failed");
        goto fail;
    }

    printf("[Server] Bind socket\n");
    if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, addrlen) < 0) {
        perror("Bind failed");
        goto fail;
    }

    printf("[Server] Listening on socket\n");
    if (listen(socket_fd, 3) < 0) {
        perror("Listen failed");
        goto fail;
    }

    printf("[Server] Wait for clients to connect ..\n");
    while (connections < WORKER_NUM) {
        addrlen = sizeof(addr); // <-- add this!
        client_sock_fds[connections] =
            accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &addrlen);
        if (client_sock_fds[connections] < 0) {
            perror("Accept failed");
            break;
        }

        if (sockaddr_to_string((struct sockaddr *)&addr, ip_string,
                               sizeof(ip_string) / sizeof(ip_string[0])) != 0) {
            printf("[Server] failed to parse client address\n");
            goto fail;
        }

        printf("[Server] Client connected (%s)\n", ip_string);
        if (pthread_create(&workers[connections], NULL, run,
                           &client_sock_fds[connections]) != 0) {
            perror("Create a worker thread failed");
            shutdown(client_sock_fds[connections], SHUT_RDWR);
            break;
        }

        connections++;
    }

    if (connections == WORKER_NUM) {
        printf("[Server] Achieve maximum amount of connections\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < connections; i++) { // <-- needs to be the actual thread count, not WORKER_NUM!
        pthread_join(workers[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("[Server] Shuting down ..\n");
    shutdown(socket_fd, SHUT_RDWR);
    sleep(3);
    printf("[Server] BYE \n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

fail:
    printf("[Server] Shuting down ..\n");
    if (socket_fd >= 0)
        close(socket_fd);
    sleep(3);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

That being said, you should use [`getaddrinfo()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) instead to initialize the `sockaddr_...` that you pass to `bind()`. You should not be initializing it manually at all.

```c
...
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int socket_fd = -1, res;
    ...
    struct addrinfo hints = { 0 };
    struct addrinfo *addrs = NULL;

    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "inet6") == 0)
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;
    else
        hints.ai_family = AF_INET;

    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    printf("[Server] Initializing socket address\n");
    res = getaddrinfo(NULL, "1234", &hints, &addrs);
    if (res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(res));
        goto fail;
    }

    printf("[Server] Create socket\n");
    socket_fd = socket(addrs->ai_family, addrs->ai_socktype, addrs->ai_protocol);
    if (socket_fd < 0) {
        perror("Create socket failed");
        freeaddrinfo(addrs);
        goto fail;
    }

    printf("[Server] Bind socket\n");
    if (bind(socket_fd, addrs->ai_addr, addrs->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
        perror("Bind failed");
        freeaddrinfo(addrs);
        goto fail;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(addrs);

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying to understand why this error is only thrown on Unix systems and not Linux systems. This is because if you look at how the `bind()` function is implemented in Linux, it only throws an Invalid argument error only when the `addrlen` passed to the `bind()` function is lesser than the `addrlen` of `struct sockaddr_in` or `struct sockaddr_in6` respectively. Hence my question is is this the expected behaviour for Unix systems?

Comment: It is obviously implementation-defined behavior. Don't rely on it. Use the real size of the actual struct used (`sockaddr_in` vs `sockaddr_in6`) and you will be fine on all platforms.